# Method adding element to array of ints

Tags: java, arrays

I need help with creating a method that adds input int to an array, and returning a message if array is already full.

I have class `Lista` with 3 fields `numbers`, `capacity` and `size`. Than I have a counstructor taking int as parameter and seting the capacity of array for the object of Lista class. So far i have this code:

```
public class Lista {

private int[] numbers;
private int capacity;
private int size;

public Lista (int capacity) {
    this.size = 0;
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.numbers = new int[capacity];
}

public void addElement(int element) {

        }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lista lista = new Lista(10);
    lista.addElement(1);
    lista.addElement(2);
    lista.addElement(3);

    System.out.println(lista.numbers[1]);
```

I've tried with loops and ArrayLIst but nothing i wrotr realy worked. WHat would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement your `addElement` method like so:

```
public void addElement(int element) {
       if(size == capacity) {
           System.out.println("array is full");
           return;
       }
       numbers[size++] = element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to throw exception when list is already full and you try to insert next element to it:

```
class List {
    private int[] numbers;
    private int nextIndex;

    public List(int capacity) {
        this.numbers = new int[capacity];
    }

    public void addElement(int element) {
        if (nextIndex < numbers.length) {
            numbers[nextIndex] = element;
            nextIndex++;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("list is full");
        }
    }

    public int capacity() {
        return numbers.length;
    }

    public int size() {
        return nextIndex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried with loops and ArrayLIst but nothing i wrotr realy worked.
>   WHat would be the best way to do it?

You use an array to store your values, so you don't need to use ArrayList (it is an alternative).
A loop is for iterating. You don't need it either.

> I need help with creating a method that adds input int to an array,
>   and returning a message if array is already full.

Returning a textual message is not really the way which an API should be designed. It should rather returns a boolean to indicate the result of the invocation.
For example, look at the `boolean add(E e)` method of the `Collection` interface.

So, you should change the declaration of `addElement()` in order to return a boolean to indicate if the element was added or not (the last one when the max capcacity was reached).

```
public boolean addElement(int element) {
       if(size == capacity) {
           return false;
       }
       numbers[size++] = element;
       return true;
}
```

If you want to output a textual message, you could test the value of the boolean :

```
if (!myLista.addElement(5)){
   System.out.println("max capacity added. Cannot add the element");
}
```